# Is there a way to capture the key being pressed in a 'key_press_event'?

Tags: event-handling, pygtk

I am trying to build a basic interface using pyGTK, where based on the key being pressed, I evoke different functions.

I understand that using the 'connect' method, I can capture events such as a keypress or a click, like so:

```
self.btn1.connect("clicked", self.funcRec)
self.btn1.connect("key_press_event", self.funcRec)
```

Doing this will call the funcRec function when there is a key press event, or when the button is being clicked.
But I am not able to find a way to capture the actual key being pressed and trigger different functions. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. I used a function that captures the event and gets the value of the key press event.

First you 'connect' and get the 'key_press_event' and trigger a callback function

```
self.connect("key-press-event", self.on_key_down)
```

where 'on_key_down' callback function is defined as,

```
def on_key_down(self, widget, event):
  key = event.keyval
  if key == gtk.keysyms.Right:
    self.onRightPress(self, widget)
  if key == gtk.keysyms.Left:
    self.onRightPress(self, widget)
```